# Configuring MySQL DataSource in JavaEE without actual password

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am setting up my JavaEE environment as I have other times in the past. I have always placed the actual password in the DataSource config to access the database. I am wondering if it is prudent/possible/necessary to use a hashed value for the password instead of the actual. Or, is there some other, best practice, way of avoiding use of the actual password?

This may not even be a necessary precaution, but I am curious to know and Googling proved fruitless for me.

Here is how I have set things up in my META-INF --> context.xml in the past (with some settings omitted for simplicity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource
    name="jdbc/mydatabasename"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://mydburl"
    username="myusername"
    password="actualpassword"
  />
</Context>
```

Basically, is there something else I can/should put in place of `password="actualpassword"` to make things more secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard way of doing this, but most vendors have implemented something, e.g.  [JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Encrypting_Data_Source_Passwords.html), [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Securing+Passwords) or [Glassfish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablnp/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I have wanted to try one of these anyway, so maybe now is a good time.